# prevent form submission from enter button

Tags: javascript, ajax, chat

i have a live chat messaging system whenever user press enter button it refreshes the page i have tried using prevent default code also but did not worked for me.... here is the code and if there is any problem in the below code please let me know as i'm totally new to website programming

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.btn-success').click(function() {
        var form_name  = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        var obj = jQuery(this);
        jQuery(".ajax_indi").show();
        switch (form_name) {
            case "npost":
            var message = jQuery("#message").val();
            break;
            default:
            alert("something went wrong!");
        }
        if((jQuery(message) == ''))
        {
           alert("Message Cannot be Empty");
           jQuery(".ajax_indi").hide();
           return false;
        } else {
        jQuery(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        jQuery(this).prop('value', 'Loading...');
        jQuery(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        }
        var str = jQuery("#"+form_name).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chat.php",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                jQuery('#chat1').append(html);
                obj.attr("disabled", false);
                obj.prop('value', 'Post');
                obj.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                jQuery(".ajax_indi").hide();
                document.getElementById(form_name).reset();
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Edited part

```
<form id="npost"  name="npost">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here..." 
    type="text" name="message">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="npost" >Send</button>
```

Comment: Is .button-success a submit button? Please provide some more detail like the form you are submitting

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh yes it is a button name

Comment: Put your HTML code as well

Comment: I mean is it a button with type="submit" ?

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh now see

Comment: There are a few errors in your jQuery code. e.g. (jQuery(message) == '') here the message variable will be undefined as you have defined in switch construct so it will not be available here

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh So what should i do Now?

Comment: I can't find element with id="message" in your html form. I think you forgot to add it. Also, I have updated my answer. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent from submitting the form you can use `return false` if you want to stop executing the function and stop submitting it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use preventDefault in order to stop form submission on clicking enter because by default form gets submitted when anyone presses enter. So use preventDefault like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.btn-success').click(function(e){         // added e
 e.preventDefault();                              // added this line
var form_name  = jQuery(this).attr('title');
var obj = jQuery(this);
jQuery(".ajax_indi").show();
var message = '';
        switch (form_name)
        {

        case "npost":
                var message = jQuery("#message").val();
        break;
        default:
        alert("something went wrong!");
        }

        if((jQuery(message) == ''))
        {
             alert("Message Cannot be Empty");
             jQuery(".ajax_indi").hide();
             return false;
        } else {
            jQuery(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            jQuery(this).prop('value', 'Loading...');
            jQuery(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        }

        var str = jQuery("#"+form_name).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chat.php",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                jQuery('#chat1').append(html);
                obj.attr("disabled", false);
                obj.prop('value', 'Post');
                obj.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                jQuery(".ajax_indi").hide();
                document.getElementById(form_name).reset();
            }
        });
           });

       });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You should not stop form default action you to prevent enter key default answer here is the code to prevent.

```
$('#npost').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
   if (e.which== 13) { 
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
});
```